# Cpython interpretter / IronPython interpretter No module named clr

Tags: python, clr, visual-studio-2012, ironpython

i'm using IronPython and i want to create some windows form, 
i want to create a windows form with some button, and i want to do this in visual studio with iron python,
i'm using visual studio 2012 integrated edition,
each time i create an "ironpython windows form" project, when i want to run it, it says:

> The project is currently set to use the .NET debugger for IronPython
>   debugging but the project is configured to start with a CPython
>   interpreter. To fix this change the debugger type in project
>   properties->Debug->Launch mode

when i change debugger to Standard Python Launcher, it says:

> ImportError: No module named clr

what should i do?

Comment: Have you tried telling it to use IronPython?

Comment: i don't know if i got your point or not, 
but actually i have to go to the project properties->Debug->Launch  and set "launch mode" to something other than "IronPython.net Launcher" in order to get rid of the first error message,
and it causes the second error

Answer (score 6):

I got the same error and resolved it with these steps:

I changed the project properties
General>Interpreter to IronPython 2.7
Debug>Launch mode to IronPython(.NET) launcher

At first I didn't see IronPython as an interpreter option to select from. I added the path to IronPython installation to my Path System variable, restarted Visual Studio and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is an old question, but I ran into the same thing today, and did not find any satisfactory answers.

I'm working with a new install of Visual Studio 2015 - Community under Windows 8.1. After installing a bunch of additional add-ons and tool boxes, I thought it would be complete. I had an IronPython debug option in VS, but it had not been (successfully) installed!

If you're having issues with IronPython, look in `C:\Program Files (x86)`, and verify the directory `IronPython 2.7` exists.

(IronPython 2.7 is available at
http://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/169382.)

Once you have verified installation was successful, setup your development environment:

- Create a Python project in Visual Studio
- At the bottom of the Project menu, click `<project name> Properties`
- On the General page, select IronPython 2.7 as your interpreter
- On the Debug page, set Launch mode to IronPython (.Net) launcher
- Finally, click on Debug Standard Library.

Using that setup, I was able to generate a blank Windows form application, and start it with/without debugging.

Answer (score 0):

OK dudes, 
i tell you how i solved the problem,
i reinstalled everything from the scratch, i used to use visual studio express, but i installed the "professional" version,
then i reinstalled everything from http://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/81726 
and suddenly all things worked fine in the console,
then voila, ironpython windows form project in visual studio is working now :)